# JS, что делает этот синтаксис?

Tags: javascript

читаю о js, и встретил такой код:

```
(function() {

  var a = 2;

  eval(' alert(a) '); // 2

})()
```

Конкретно про скобки оборачивающие анонимную функции и следующие за ними скобки. Что они делают ? Для чего они ? Что позволяют решить ?

Comment: @yolosora, не вводите людей в заблуждение и почитайте о IIFE. Например здесь https://getinstance.info/articles/javascript/immediately-invoked-function-expressions/

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd точняк, без точки с запятой показалось странно обрезанным куском кода)

Comment: @yolosora, кстати можете и ответ сформировать, если Вам не трудно конечно :) В дополнение к статье выше, можно добавить, что такую конструкцию в основном используют как способ инкапсулировать выполняемый код. Например Вы написали либу, что часто используете, и поделились с другими. Код либы можно обернуть в такую конструкцию, чтобы данные в ней не были затронуты сторонним кодом.